# Ubuntu UEFI Windows 8.1 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have installed Win8 and Ubuntu side by side before in the past and had issues with booting which were fixed perfectly the first time using boot-repair.  This time, I installed Win8.1 and Ubuntu with the same issue.  Boot-repair also fixed it.  After running Windows a few times, I attempted to reboot and got the following:

```
Error:  Unknown Filesystem
grub rescue>
```

I was able to find the windows UEFI boot file doing a boot options from the BIOS and successfully boot Win8 from: `MS/Boot/bootmgrfw.efi`.  When I booted into Ubuntu Live from a USB and reinstalled and re-ran boot-repair, it was much more involved and asked me to open a couple of terminal windows and paste in some additional commands.  At the end running, it said everything was good but I still have the same issues.  It appears it made backup copies of my UEFI boot files because now I need to boot `bkpbootmgrfw.efi` to successfully load Win8.1 while `bootmgrfw.efi` gives the same unknown filesystem error.

The URL I got after running boot-repair the second time is http://paste.ubuntu.com/6514148/  Is there a way to manually fix the UEFI boot or should I blow away UBUNTU, repair Windows and then reinstall UBUNTU ?

Update:  I can boot `\efi\ubuntu\grub64.efi` and get to the normal grub boot menu which I can load either Win8 or Ubuntu.  It also shows the boot file for Win8 to be the backup file.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. If you boot /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi do you get the GRUB menu too?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer please.